# POSIX spawn.h and /sys/wait.h on Visual Studio Windows platform

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, posix

This is similar to a question in a very old thread (7 year old thread) available here: [can't get my code to run from a programming book(c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421836/cant-get-my-code-to-run-from-a-programming-bookc/) (So, instead of posing this question there, I wanted to post as a new thread.)

Essentially, the following code from book [Professional Multicore Programming](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Multicore-Programming-Design-and-Implementation-for-C-Developers.productCd-0470289627,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) does not compile because header files `spawn.h` and `sys/wait.h` are missing.

```
  using namespace std;
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <spawn.h>
  #include <sys/wait.h>

  int main(int argc,char *argv[],char *envp[])
  {

     pid_t ChildProcess;
     pid_t ChildProcess2;
     int RetCode1;
     int RetCode2;
     int Value;
     RetCode1 = posix_spawn(&ChildProcess,"find_code",NULL,
                            NULL,argv,envp);
     RetCode2 = posix_spawn(&ChildProcess2,"find_code",NULL,
                            NULL,argv,envp);
     wait(&Value);
     wait(&Value);
     return(0);
  }
```

The accepted answer on that thread suggests downloading the `pthread` package from [here](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/).

However, even that installation does not ship with `spawn.h` or `sys/wait.h`. The only header files in the installation are `pthread.h`, `sched.h` and `semaphore.h`. No mention of `spawn.h` or `sys/wait.h`.

Is there a way to get the code to run on Windows Visual Studio?

I already tried doing a google search for these missing header files, but only general comments about what that file should do are around. For instance, the following [page](https://www.mankier.com/0p/spawn.h).

Comment: Why not just use the [windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx)? And if you are looking to cross platforms, I'd imagine that [boost.process](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/process.html) would be the ticket. Can't say for sure as I've never used it.

Comment: @lakeweb `_spawnl()` seems to have different definition from `posix_spawn()`. So, I am sure simply changing `posix_swawn` to `_spawnl` will NOT work. I want to get the code to compile first and then make improvements/changes such as using different libraries/apis.

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't see the posix headers working with the Microsoft OS. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: A win32 equivalent would be to `CreateProcess` and then `WaitForSingleObject` on the process handle. Since you have multiple processes, `WaitForMultipleObjects` might be more appropriate.

Comment: Directly addressing the question, Windows has very weak support for POSIX. I doubt you will be able to find headers (and backing library) without pulling in a third party POSIX layer like cygwin.

Comment: use `std::thread`.